# Display Advertising Attribution

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, goal-tracking

Right now, we're currently running display ads through Google AdWords simultaneously with our traditional search campaigns.

In Google Analytics, we can see paths to conversion that include display impressions and/or display clicks. Using last-touch attribution for display ads doesn't show it's true value since they are more so used for awareness.

My question is, has anyone set up a system to show the true value of display advertising and its effect on search ads? If so, what was the model you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else out there struggling with display attribution, this is probably the best article I've read. It really helps understand the different attribution models, and how to create one based on your needs.

[Multi-Channel Attribution Modeling: The Good, Bad and Ugly Models](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/multi-channel-attribution-modeling-good-bad-ugly-models/)